# How should I manage temporary downloads in Android app?

Tags: java, android

I have an async task which in `doInBackgrund` is setting up a connection to perform a GET, takes the response to an `OutputStream` and it ends up writing a file to sd.

Such file is actually an mp3 which will be reproduced once using a `MediaPlayer` and forgotten, not ever used again.

This is how I'm doing it all ...

```
@Override
protected File doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        String urlString = ttsURL + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        System.out.println(url.toString());

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36");
        Log.d("QUERY PROPERTIES",urlConnection.getRequestProperties().toString());
        urlConnection.connect();

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {

        }
        System.out.println(urlConnection.getContentEncoding() == null);
        System.out.printf(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        System.out.println(urlConnection.getHeaderFields().toString());
        input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        File sdDir = getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = sdDir + "/" + params[0] + ".mp3";
        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
        return null;

    } finally{
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();

        }
    }
    Log.i("Response", "Done");
    return new File(file);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(File f) {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(f.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.start();

}
```

So, as it can be seen at `onPostExecute`, that file is being used to play the audio. Although I'm not deleting the file in the code I providing, I wonder what's best alternative for this case ... I know I could attempt to delete the file when the player it's at `onPlaybackCompleted` state, but I'd like a way much simple and convenient approch for temporal files.

Answer (score 1):

use a separate folder, and when you are sure that user is leaving your app, clear that directory.

Comment: That means when `onPause`, `onStopped` states .. uh?

Comment: onPause should not be used cause it might be called many other reasons,
onStop can be used but you need to be careful whether user is reallly going out of your app.
My suggestion you should override your onBackPressed, and clear that directory there.

Comment: How developer can make sure that user is intentionally leaving the app or activity , what if call comes during file is playing.

Comment: onBackPressed sufficiently indicates that user has himself pressed the back button, Otherwise it wouldn't be called.
and for other states e.g. onPause & onStop, dev can't say for sure. said the same thing in the previous comment.

Comment: @diegoaguilar   In order to make sure that user exits from the application, you can prompt a dialog asking users permission to exit from the app. There you can put a message as "if you exit, this file will be selected" or something like that. If user confirms the exit , no worries, delete the file and exit the app. If not dismiss the dialog and stay as it is.